# Selenium And Selenium-webdriver

Tags: discussion, documentation

When I am searching about Selenium at stackoverflow documentation beta, I found two tags Selenium and Selenium-webdriver. My question is these two are different? If these are different, how?

Comment: Well, from my understanding, there's more to Selenium than just the webdriver. So I'd expect documentation about those non-webdriver things to be in the selenium tag. You could also use the discussion feature to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium/1840/getting-started-with-selenium/discussion

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I am new to selenium, so I just confused are there two kinds of selenium? Or not? Now, I see. Thanks you! I expected someone to explain about non-webdriver things:-)

Answer (score 1):

When people talk about Selenium, I would assume the overwhelming majority is actually talking about Selenium Webdriver.

Selenium consists of 2 things, the selenium webdriver and selenium IDE, which is just a firefox plugin that allows you to record user interaction in firefox and turn it into a script so that it can be replayed.

You can read about it here: https://www.seleniumhq.org/